# What is the meaning of this error: example: Is a directory

Tags: command-line, fuse

I'm trying out fuse with [this](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) tutorial. When I try to run the example using the command below, I  get this error:

```
memsql@memsql-virtual-machine:~$ ~/fuse-2.9.3/example> ./hello /tmp/fuse -d
bash: /home/memsql/fuse-2.9.3/example: Is a directory
```

What is the meaning of this error? I'm following the tutorial exactly. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

In the example

```
~/fuse/example>
```

is a prompt, not part of the command. The command issued is:

```
./hello /tmp/fuse -d
```

Where `hello` is [this code](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/helloworld.html) compiled. *(Compile line at top of page)*.

Actually, due to the redirect, if you have `hello` compiled in the home directory of your user:

```
/home/memsql/
```

the file is overwritten (as empty) due to the `>` redirect from the command, which produces no output. Else, an empty file named *hello* is created.

---

Bash interprets you as trying to issue a directory as a command, as in:

```
$ /homeEnter
bash: /home: Is a directory

$ /proc/Enter
bash: /proc/: Is a directory

$ /home/ asdf asdf asdf blah blahEnter
bash: /home/: Is a directory
```

---

So in your example:

```
$ ls -F1 ~
bar
Documents/
fuse-2.9.3/example/
gaz

$ ~/fuse-2.9.3/example> ./hello /tmp/fuse -d
bash: /home/memsql/fuse-2.9.3/example: Is a directory

$ ls -F1 ~
bar
Documents/
fuse-2.9.3/example/
gaz
hello  <--- new empty file
```

Comment: It would be nice if the markup allowed for calling out markup in the code blocks. +1 BTW, nice work!

Comment: @slm: Thank you. Fixed it. Have had some trouble with `<pre>` and `<code>` tags earlier, but they are in [the list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/220649), so should work.

Answer (score 1):

Is `/home/memsql` a mounted filesystem from somewhere else? `df -h .` while in that directory will tell you.

#### Example

Here's a locally mounted drive.

```
$ df -h .
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_home
                      245G  137G   97G  59% /home
```

Here's one that's mounted from another server, `mulder`.

```
$ df -h .
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
mulder:/export/raid1/home/sam
                      917G  560G  312G  65% /home/sam
```